# How to draw one rectangle in ArcObjects?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcobjects, c#, optimization, map-drawing

Is there button in ArcObjects "draw rectangle" such as in openlayers?

***Update***

Well, I use this code for drawing:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = Map1.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay;
screenDisplay.StartDrawing(screenDisplay.hDC, (System.Int16)
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRgbColor rgbColor = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RgbColor();
rgbColor.Red = 255;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IColor color = rgbColor;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISimpleFillSymbol simpleFillSymbol = new
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SimpleFillSymbol();
simpleFillSymbol.Color = color;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol symbol = simpleFillSymbol as
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRubberBand rubberBand = new
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RubberEnvelope();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry geometry = rubberBand.TrackNew(screenDisplay,
    symbol);
screenDisplay.SetSymbol(symbol);
screenDisplay.DrawRectangle(geometry as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IEnvelope);
screenDisplay.FinishDrawing();
...
ArcGisToolbar.CurrentTool.Deactivate();
ArcGisToolbar.CurrentTool = null;
ICommand command = this.ArcGisToolbar.CommandPool.get_Command(3); // button "pan"
Map1.CurrentTool = (ITool)command;
```

But there is a problem. When I activate this instrument (button "select") again, I already start selecting the area (from the point, where I begin drawing the polygon)

Comment: what sdk Version do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would use:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRubberBand rubberBand = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RubberPolygonClass();
```

instead of using the RubberEnvelope method

then later do:

```
screenDisplay.DrawPolygon(geometry);
```

instead of screenDisplay.DrawRectangle(...)

see if that gets you further.

When getting Feedback for the rectangle via mouse Events I'd do the following:
In OnMouseDown use:

```
INewEnvelopeFeedback envFb = new NewEnvelopeFeedback();
            envFb.Display = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
            envFb.Start(pt);
```

assign the envFb to a IDisplayfeedback df

In OnMouseMove do:

```
df.MoveTo(pt)
```

In OnMouseUp do:

```
IEnvelope env = ((INewEnvelopeFeedback)df).Stop();
```

pt is always the position of your mouse cursor.

Comment: Thanks. I draw rectangle, not polygon. Nowdays, I use two events: OnMouseDown (the left upper point) OnMouseUp (the right lower point, then draw rectangle)

Comment: Yes that should work using the INewEnvelopeFeedback for instance. So is your issue solved or what is the remaining problem?

Comment: I can draw rectangle on the Map. But I write additional code to functions: _OnMouseUp _OnMouseDown. I think it is not good. When I use example with "screenDisplay.DrawRectangle" I have the problem with instrument "select". When i activate this tool again I am already starting draw the rectangle (but I must only select the area). instrument "select". When i activate this tool again I already starting draw the polygone (but I must only select elemnts).

Comment: what Instrument "select" are you referring to? Is that a custom tool made by you or some Standard selection tool in ArcMap? I edit my original answer to add some info on how I'd handle the mouse Events.

Comment: I wonder whether the problem is that you don't call stop() for the envelopeFeedback (see my edited post above). Additional code in the mouseevent functions is generally seen not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of useful information and snippets of code in the ArcObjects online help from which you can start. For instance:

- [How to draw a polygon on the screen](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000238000000)
- [Draw Polygon Snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000003r000000)
- [Creating a custom button and tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001ms000000#CreatingButtonTool)